# From pandas dataframe save to csv file without double quotes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have excel file with special character. I want to write the DataFrame without the double quote, but receive error. Help is very much appreciated.

## To generate operation commands from excel to text format

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

filename = r'In_file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)

df1 = df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]

df1.to_csv('out_file3.txt', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-70ff5701bfb8> in <module>
      9 df1 = df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]
     10 
---> 11 df1.to_csv('out_file3.txt', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

> NameError: name 'csv' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `csv` package import:

```py
import csv  # <- HERE!
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

filename = r'In_file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)

df1 = df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]

df1.to_csv('out_file3.txt', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```